# Opensuse issues with some hypervisor

Tags: vmware, opensuse, esxi, hypervisor, sles

I'm trying a particular software in a VM on VBox and VMWare Player with SLES and Opensuse Leap, everything works fine. The same setup on VMWare ESXi and ProxMox is unstable.
The software consists in many services. Some of these services simply don't start.
Curiously enough, if I copy the problematic VM from ESXi to VMWare Player it works like a charm.
Before giving some more details, are there known issues with Suse products (Tumbleweed, Leap and SLES) and specific hypervisors like ESXi or ProxMox?

Answer (score 0):

SLES on VMWare looks like it's end of life since 2014, so probably not surprising it doesn't behave well on the recent version of SLES on recent version of ESXi...
(https://www.vmware.com/products/sles-for-vmware.html)

You can check the compatibility here:
(https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software)

Might also want to make sure if you installed vmware tools? hope this helps.